# Cakephp webroot displaying in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I renamed my cakephp app folder to 1.0 While I am checking in my local its displaying as 
follows http://www.sample.com:80/cakephp/1.0/webroot/index.php

When I am make the folder name as app then  http://www.sample.com:80/cakephp.

I want to remove that webroot/index.php from the URL. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just be a matter of replacing 'app' with '1.0' in your top level .htaccess file.

So, currently you'll have something like this in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And just replace app with 1.0:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ 1.0/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) 1.0/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Yes I made the same thing previously. It didn't worked. Let me try one more time

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint - Next time you've actually tried the correct solution please mention it in the question in the first place.